# C++ parametrized constructor

Tags: c++

i was wondering if parametrized constructor **should** always have only parameters that actually initialize class' attributes. For example, in calling:

```
Texture background("C:\Documents\Images\background.png");
```

What if i don't need to store the file path?

Comment: I've never heard of any such rule.  Where did you come up with the idea that it might be discouraged?  What might be a problem with your example, and others like it, is if the file pointed to does not exist (eg., if you failed to escape your backslashes), then you have to think hard about how you want to handle that failure.

Comment: I'm assuming you actually need to use the path, even if you don't save it. In that case, provide it. If you're going to load it later, then you don't really need it in the constructor; you can have a public method for providing it. But there's nothing wrong with providing a parameter as an option. The ability to have various constructors is one of the greatest features of OOP.

Comment: Funny -- Tell that to `std::ifstream` or `std::ofstream` that what is being done is controversial.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, it's not controversial or illegal.  It just depends on how you feel about constructors that throw, and if you don't want those then it's a headache.  To mandate that the first use of an object be a call to "DidConstructorSucceed()" would probably be silly; especially considering that it separates the cause of the error (the path) from the call that discovers that it wasn't any good).

Comment: It's a fuzzy line. There's definitely a point where a function should be a static factory rather than a constructor, but I also don't necessarily think that point is "all constructor arguments must literally be instance variables". I think this falls squarely into "use your own judgement as a reasonable programmer". If it looks like a constructor, make it a constructor. If it's doing a lot of obviously non-constructor work, make it a standalone (or static) factory function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object constructor takes whatever parameters are necessary for returning **a valid and functional object**. You may allow constructors with extra parameters for syntax sugar, but at the very least, your object should be a valid one. In your case, I don't think a texture makes sense without a file used as texture, so I think removing that parameter is not recommended.

Keep in mind though that you should also aim for making your code easy to test. In that case, complex constructors can be a pain when you want to instantiate an object for testing specif methods. In the end, it is more of a decision process.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to store the path, then don't pass it to the constructor! :)

Parametrized constructors are intended to ensure that all information is available when the object is instanciated. So pass only the information that is neccessary.

If you want to follow the RAII idiom, then pass all requered resource to the constructor and release the resources (if the object locks them, like a file or a port).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with accepting a parameter which isn't directly stored in the class.  Obviously if it doesn't affect the class at all, then that's just a waste of time, but you might accept something like a PRNG seed which you use to fill your class with randomised state, and have no reason to retain the seed beyond that point.

However, passing in a file path which you mean to access within the constructor is dangerous, as there could be any number of problems that come up during that process.  You really don't want trouble like that in your constructor.

In avoiding potential failure cases in your constructor you end deferring things like file access until after construction.  Consequently the constructor really doesn't need the information because it makes more sense to pass it to the method you use to access the file where you can handle errors more easily.

Comment: I know that constructors don't have returning value and in my case (loading files through file path) it might a serious problem, but despite the fact, it's much more comfortable to use constructor instead of public method... i also couldn't remember if i have ever seen constructor with "extra" parameters and thought it's something like unwritten rule... that's why i asked. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I understand that you can write much more straightforward code if you can have the constructor finish the initialisation job at the outset.  But what's your plan for when your constructor finds that "c:documentsimages^Hackground.png" isn't a valid filename?